# How to retrieve data from firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an admin panel app for firebase.
But I am unable to retrieve data of admin user from firebase.
The app crashes when I press the login button.
Can someone give the method of retrieving the data of admins from my database and check if it matches the credentials entered by the user.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.capi.ccecommerceadmin.Model.Admin;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    Button signIn;
    EditText email, password;
    String adminemail;

    FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        signIn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        email = findViewById(R.id.login_email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.login_password);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final String str_email = email.getText().toString();
        final String str_password = password.getText().toString();

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getAdmin(str_email, str_password);
            }
        });
    }

    private void getAdmin(final String str_email, final String str_password)
    {

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Admins").orderByChild("isAdmin").equalTo(true);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Admin admin = snapshot.getValue(Admin.class);

                adminemail = admin.getEmail();
                if (adminemail.equals(str_email))
                {
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(str_email, str_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, adminemail+" and "+str_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am new to android programming...

If you want some other class I will post it also...................................................

...................................................................................................

here is my database structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftt15.png

here is my stackrace:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at com.capi.ccecommerceadmin.LoginActivity$2.onDataChange(LoginActivity.java:65)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
       at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6816)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1567)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1455)
2020-07-06 10:59:38.422 1839-27996/? E/KioskModeService: There's no matched data
2020-07-06 10:59:38.440 1839-27996/? E/KioskModeService: There's no matched data
2020-07-06 10:59:38.493 1839-27996/? E/SemDvfsHintManager:  mHintTimeout : 500
2020-07-06 10:59:38.496 1839-27996/? E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{8dd224ad0 u0 com.capi.ccecommerceadmin/.SplashActivity t2398 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{efa2eb4 8057:com.capi.ccecommerceadmin/u0a314}
2020-07-06 10:59:38.515 1839-1858/? E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() returned.
2020-07-06 10:59:38.592 1839-3440/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
2020-07-06 10:59:38.597 1839-3440/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 108)
2020-07-06 10:59:38.598 9316-9316/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 92)
2020-07-06 10:59:38.614 755-843/? E/PBSessionCacheImpl: sessionId[3322118973208456] not persisted.
2020-07-06 10:59:38.665 1839-1943/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2020-07-06 10:59:38.930 1839-1865/? E/WindowManager: Unhandled exception in Window Manager
   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
       at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:230)
       at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:1003)
       at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
       at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:185)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:928)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:705)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:637)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:916)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
       at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: where is stacktrace

Comment: hold a minute i am posting it

Comment: Log this admin.getEmail() and check what it returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we can provide more accurate answers you should post your stack trace. By looking at your code, I think that the reason your app crashes is that the email and the password your function receives is **null**. Firstly, you use the **final keyword** in front of the email and password which means that the value cant be modified. Secondly, you initialize the variables on the **onCreate** method which means they shouldn't have any value in them (they should be null).

```
final String str_email = email.getText().toString();
final String str_password = password.getText().toString();
```

Lastly, you should retrieve the values from the edit texts each time you press the button so you can have the latest information your users have entered in them. You must perform general validation to your inputs like if the values are different from null and their lengths are larger from 3 (this number changes depending on the specification of the app) or if the email he enters is a valid email.

```
signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String str_email = email.getText().toString();
        String str_password = password.getText().toString();
        if (str_email != null && str_email != null) {
            if (str_email.length() > 3 && str_password.length() > 3) {
                getAdmin(str_email, str_password);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note, the above code is just an example. I havent tested it and you should display messages to users depending the email/password is valid or not.

Comment: it is still crashing

Comment: It says that the string admin email is null. Check if any data are returned from firebase. And specifically if the string adminemail is null or not.

Comment: can you send the code by seeing my database structure I have given

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase realtime database then you can follow this simple strategy for sign up by looping through firebase children:

```
 DatabaseReference data=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

 data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            int num=0;
            if(snapshot.exists()
            {
            for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if(ds.child("email).getValue().toString().equals(email)&&ds.child("password").getValue().toString().equals(password))
                {
                   //Do Login
                   num=1;
                 }
            }
           }
        if(num==0)
            //print Invalid credentials
       }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```